# Is there a way to determine whether a source for rooting instructions is reliable?

Tags: rooting

I'm considering rooting an ATT S3, and came across [this](http://galaxys3root.com/galaxy-s3-root/how-to-root-u-s-and-canada-galaxy-s3-sgh-t999sgh-i747sph-l710-fail-proofnoob-proof/) guide:

The guide links to some [file](http://downloadandroidrom.com/file/GalaxyS3ATT/rooting/GalaxyS3RootUSCanada.zip) that is supposed to contain both a file to be copied into the phone and the tools for flashing the CWM.

Are there any reasonable assurances that this file and tools are free of malware? Are there any peer reviewed sources that I could use with a greater degree of trust?